# Action per turn in Savage worlds?

Tags: savage-worlds, actions

I was looking at the [Savage Worlds test drive PDF](http://www.peginc.com/Downloads/SWEX/TD06.pdf) and was wondering how the action economy goes. Basically for non attack actions in a turn like agility tricks or trying to intimidate an opponent. Are these instead of an attack? One action in addition to an attack? or no real limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer looking at savage worlds [showdown](http://www.peginc.com/Downloads/Showdown/Showdown.pdf):

> Each additional action attempted in a 
>   round subtracts 2 from all the figure’s trait 
>   rolls. If an adventurer wants to fire a gun 
>   with one hand and slice at an adjacent foe 
>   with a knife in his other hand, for instance, 
>   he subtracts 2 from both rolls. If he also 
>   wanted to Taunt someone at the same time, 
>   he subtracts 4 from all three rolls.